# level of the child in the table recursion php?

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is to deduce the level of nesting relative to id. Here is an example of db:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22b0d2/1

Here is an example of the php code:

```
function getCats($res){

    $levels = array();
    $tree = array();
    $cur = array();

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

        $cur = &$levels[$rows['id']];
        $cur['parent_id'] = $rows['parent_id'];
        $cur['name'] = $rows['name'];

        if($rows['parent_id'] == 0){
            $tree[$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }
        else{
            $levels[$rows['parent_id']]['children'][$rows['id']] = &$cur;
        }

    }

    return $tree;

}

function getTree($arr){

    $out = '';
    $counter = 1;

    $out .= '<ul>';
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
        $out .= '<li><a href="?id='.$k.'">'.$v['name'].'</a></li>';
        if(!empty($v['children'])){
            $out .= getTree($v['children']);
        }

    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
    return $out;

}
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testids');
$res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id"); 
$cats = getCats($res); 
echo getTree($cats);
```

[image: Result Example]

Please help remake the function so that it's like this:
Just look not from the `<ul>`, but from the `<table>`. If we look from the `id = 1`, then at the first level we have `id 2` and `id 3`, and on the second level `id 5`, because they are children from `id 1`.
[image: Image Level Example]

```
    Array
(
    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [parent_id] =&gt; 0
            [name] =&gt; name1
            [children] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [parent_id] =&gt; 1
                            [name] =&gt; name2
                            [children] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [4] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [parent_id] =&gt; 2
                                            [name] =&gt; name4
                                            [children] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [5] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [parent_id] =&gt; 4
                                                            [name] =&gt; name5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [parent_id] =&gt; 1
                            [name] =&gt; name3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: So you want your results ordered by the ID column of the table?

Comment: can you print_r($cats);

Comment: Can you post array instead of image?

Comment: It's fast examle for mysql, no more. Added a picture with `print_r($cats);`

Comment: Ok, added array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
/*
$ray = array(
    array('id' => 1,'name' => 'name1','parent_id' => 0),
    array('id' => 2,'name' => 'name2','parent_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 3,'name' => 'name3','parent_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 4,'name' => 'name4','parent_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 5,'name' => 'name5','parent_id' => 4)
);
*/

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testids');
$res = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY id"); 

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $data['ids'][$row['id']]        = $row['name'];

    if(isset($data['level'][$row['parent_id']])){
        $level = $data['level'][$row['parent_id']] + 1;
    } else {
        $level = 0;
    }

    $data['level'][$row['id']] = $level;
}

echo '
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>';
foreach($data['level'] as $id=>$level){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$id.'</td>
        <td>'.$level.'</td>
        <td>'.$data['ids'][$id].'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '
</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions out there for this problem.

The one below is modified from https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

```
<?php

function getConnection() {
    try {
        $con = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite3') or die('connot open database');
        return $con;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        return null;
    }
}


function showChildren($parent, $level) {
    $con = getConnection();
    if ($con) {
       $stmt = $con->query('SELECT id, name, parent_id from categories WHERE parent_id = ' . $parent);
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $level . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
          echo '</tr>';
          showChildren($row['id'], $level+1);
      }
   }
}

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>LEVEL</th><th>NAME</th></tr>';

showChildren(0, 0);

echo '</table>';
```

Please note this is probably terrible PHP code.  Positive it doesn't adhear to recent coding standards, such as template strings, prepared statements and such.  However it will create the table in your question.

Comment: This is a very partial solution. How does OP use this query in *his/her specific use case*? How and where does it fit within the original code? There's a lot more info that could be added here.

Comment: Note sure how the original questioner uses this.  Honestly, its a template and I hope he/she draws from its premise and rewrites it better...

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try to rewrite the code for myself. I asked more, because I don't fully understand the logic of how to compose the code. But I'll try to understand.

Comment: The article I linked to is old but, it does a good job explaining how to interact with hierarchical data.  Although, you might have to read it a few times (I did).